# Grid like control on forms

Tags: c#, forms, grid, controls, custom-controls

Okey, so I'm working on a pathfinding program, where I would test various pathfinding algorithms. For this I prefer use a grid control,  whereat I can interract with each square, marking them as an obstacle, or a valid path. Here is a picture to demonstrate :

[image: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/grids/square-grid.png]

As far as I know, there is no built in control like this in  C# WinForms.
The only possible solution that came into my mind is using a picturebox, and divide that into squares, but that would not be what I want. So what would you use here to build this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could set up a square of panels, then assign each one into a two dimensional array (the array holds a pointer or reference to a panel). therefore creating a xy style grid to test your path finding algorithm on, when the algorithm goes on a certain panel, just change it's color.

Comment: yeah it's a nice solution. What do you think, will it work smoothly with bigger statespaces like 200x200? =/

Comment: You can also add controls to a form dynamically (I mean programmatically). So a large number of squares should not be a problem.

Comment: Yea, since this is simple, its easy to scale, and can be implemented as big as needed. So it should work rather smoothly.